# TI Basic: How to end Lbl blocks

Tags: menu, goto, ti-basic

I'm making a simple text-based battle between the player and a dragon. I use `Menu`s to have the player select from a set of options. The `Menu` then obviously goes to the `Lbl` assigned to the selected option. Within the while loop for the game I can end the `Lbl`s by using the `End` command to go back to the start of the loop, but when the player chooses the difficulty, there is no loop. How do I prevent all the subsequent Lbls from being executed in this code:

```
:Menu("DIFFICULTY?", "EASY", 00, "MEDIUM", 01, "HARD", 02)
:Lbl 00
:75->D
://some end statement
:Lbl 01
:150->D
://some end statement
:Lbl 02
:300->D
://some end statement
```

Because currently, all Labels are executed resulting in the dragon having 300 health no matter the option chosen. (I don't want a work around with scalars or some other trick, I want to know how I can emulate what I described in a general situation so I can use the technique in future programs).

Answer (score 2):

You can add another label at the end and go to it after setting the dragon's health.

Like this:

```
:Menu("DIFFICULTY?", "EASY", 00, "MEDIUM", 01, "HARD", 02)
:Lbl 00
:75->D
:GoTo 03
:Lbl 01
:150->D
:GoTo 03
:Lbl 02
:300->D
://you don't need a GoTo here since there are no more labels and Lbl 03 is the next line.
:Lbl 03
://The rest of your code...
```

This will exit out of the switch-style setup you are using and continue with the code.

Personally, I would use an `if then`, `elseIf then`, `else`, `endIf` block to achieve this goal.